# Optimize mysql query to select the values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am having a table with following column names: audit_name, audit_choice  and "slno" as auto increment primary key and no use with the output data.

The audit_name can be repeated and the audit_choice values are limited to certain values like "Passed", "Failed".

My query expected output is, getting the number of "Passed" counts and "Failed" counts for each "Audit_name".

Here is the query I tried but it takes around 3-4 minutes to execute for around 1,000 records.

```
SELECT audit_name,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Passed FROM audit AS p1
     WHERE p1.audit_name=p2.audit_name AND p1.audit_choice="Passed") AS Passed,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Failed FROM audit AS p3
     WHERE p3.audit_name=p2.audit_name AND p2.audit_choice="Failed") AS Failed
  FROM audit AS p2
  GROUP BY audit_name
```

Please suggest me how can I optimize the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  audit_name,
        SUM(audit_choice = 'Passed') AS passed,
        SUM(audit_choice = 'Failed') AS failed
FROM    audit
GROUP BY
        audit_name
```

Comment: To clarify, an expression like `audit_choice = 'Passed'` returns a Boolean value, which evaluates to 0 for False and 1 for True.

Answer (score 2):

I'd also suggest moving string values like "Passed" and "Failed" out of the table and use integer identifiers instead - they're compared much faster than strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT  audit_name,
         SUM(if(audit_choice = 'Passed',1,0)) AS passed,
         SUM(if(audit_choice = 'Failed',1,0)) AS failed
    FROM    audit
    GROUP BY
    audit_name
```

Comment: you oopsed... ,1,0 on failed should be ,0,1... as it IS, both have same count results